# have slug in urls using webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

**Problem:** From jQuery i send a post request to server, the url i call is something like this: `/get_post_data/my-custom-slug` meaning i make a request to `localhost:8080/get_post_data/my-custom-slug`. But this may change to `/my-custom-slug-two` depending upon where the user clicks in the template.  I want the url router to catch the slug and the handler function for that url to get the slug and based on the slug, i would call some model in my database fetch some data and send it back.

**Solution Strategy:**
With the above in mind here is how i have designed my url router:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/get_post_data/<my_slug:[-\w]+>', PostData)
                               ],
                              debug=True)
```

and following is the url handler function:

```
class PostData(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self, my_slug):
    self.response.out.write(my_slug)
```

The trouble is:
Ideally the output should be `my-custom-slug`
but the trouble is i dont get the my_slug variable in the handler function. 
Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, just put it this way: `('/get_post_data/([-\w]+)', TeamRates)`
make sure you put `()` and in the views as described above, things should work.